# Error in downloading.... The archived file is corrupted or damaged

Tags: php

My download.php is not working . After downloading is completed, the error on opening file is 'the archived file is corrupted or damaged '.
I dont know the reason of an error. so please help me. This code was a hard code. i tested this code by giving the name of the images. it worked right but when i retreived the images from database and tried to run this code , something went wrong.

```
      <?php

echo "<br/>" , $product_id=$_REQUEST['product_id']; 
echo "<br/>" , $query= ("SELECT image_name FROM " . $db_prefix ."product WHERE image_id = $product_id");


$test = class_exists('ZipArchive');

///$url='upload_images/';
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'photohive/upload_images/';

$zip = new ZipArchive; 
$zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'photohive/downloads/file_' . time() . '.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE); 
$result = mysql_query($query);
while( $row= @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //echo $url. $row['image_name'];
    $file_name = $url.$row['image_name'];
    if(file_exists($file_name)){
        //$zip->addFile($file_name); 
        //$zip->addFromString(basename($file_name),  file_get_contents($file_name));

        $zip->addFile(realpath($file_name), $file_name);
    }
}

$zip->close();


$encoding = 'binary';
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'photohive/downloads/file_' . time() . '.zip'; 
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition:  filename="' . basename($filename). '"');
header('Content-Type: application/x-zip' );
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: ' . $encoding);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

$file = readfile($filename);

//print($file);
exit;




 ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a space before the first <?php tag ?

Comment: Also - you've posted code that is obviously not going to work as it has debugging in e.g. [echo "<br/>" ]

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using this string to get the filename twice: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'photohive/downloads/file_' . time() . '.zip';`

In the second time, the `time()` probably will return the different timestamp, as some seconds will pass while you are compress the images.

Also using the `time()` method will bring the conflict on hi traffic sites, where you could have a possibility to get two or more requests in one second.

I suggest you to use the `tempnam()` function to generate the file. And remember to delete it after download is completed.

Here is a code:

```
$filename = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'photohive/downloads', "zip");
...
$zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
```

And remove this line:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'photohive/downloads/file_' . time() . '.zip';
```

after `$encoding = 'binary';`

Comment: Perfect, remember to vote up please. And to accept the answer.